# Bootstrap 3 columns not stacking when screen size reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a webpage for my mums baking business (and to practice my novice coding skills, otherwise I'd just use a simpler solution rather than learning bootstrap).

I've got a header, then 3 bootstrap columns below it, one with an order form, one with images of her bakes, then one with links. I've sized them 3-6-3. I like the way the page looks fullscreen on my desktop but I want the columns to stack when browser gets smaller, or on another device. Currently they just smoosh together, the images get smaller, and after a certain point, a horizontal scrollbar appears. No stacking.

I'm sure I'm either trying to use bootstrap completely wrong, or there's a few glaring errors. I've been staring at it, and trying 'fixes' on here for so long, but I can't solve my issue. Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

one problem I know, is that the  and  aren't all formatted correctly, I can solve this myself with a bit of time, I just styled it whilst I had it wrongly formatted and when I do it correctly it all looks ugly again, so I'm leaving it for another day. My main problem is the stacking issue.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
}

* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #539e8a;
}

#inner_header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Redressed', cursive;
  font-size: 333%;
  color: #f6c5be;
  top: 15px;
  left: 43%;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 17px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#myname {
  float: right;
  color: #f6c5be;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------- */

.row {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.row div {
  background: #f6c5be;
  /*border: 2px solid #539e8a;*/
}

.pics img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.main2 {
  width: 100%;
}

#media-text {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #539e8a;
}

#links-text {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #539e8a;
}

a:link {
  color: #539e8a;
}

a:visited {
  color: darkolivegreen;
}

a:hover {
  color: #539e8a;
}

#orderform-text {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #539e8a;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}

input[type=date] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}

input[type=tel] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}

select[name=orderItems] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}

textarea[name=orderBrief] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px #539e8a;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Open+Sans:wght@300&family=Redressed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mysite.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="inner_header">
      <img id="logo" src="images/newlogo.png" alt="logo, a cupcake">
      <h1>redacted</h1>
      <div id="myname">
        <p>
          by redacted
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="row" id="orderform-text">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2><b>Order Form</b></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form action="xxx.xxx.xxx" method="post">
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="address">Address:</label>
              <input type="text" name="Address">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number:</label>
              <input type="tel" name="contactNumber">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="deliveryDate">Delivery Date:</label>
              <input type="date">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="orderItems">What would you like?:</label>
              <select name="orderItems">
                <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
                <option value="Cupcakes">Cupcakes</option>
                <option value="Brownies">Brownies</option>
                <option value="Scones">Scones</option>
                <option value="Wedding Cake">Wedding Cake</option>
                <option value="Custom Order">Custom Order (detail below)</option>
              </select>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="orderBrief">Order brief:
                                 <br>
                                 <br>
                             <textarea name="orderBrief" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Tell me in detail what you would like to order!"></textarea></label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="DietaryRequirements">Dietary requirements?:
                            Vegan<input type="checkbox" name="dietaryRequirements" value="Vegan">
                            Dairy-Free<input type="checkbox" name="dietaryRequirements" value="Dairy-free (can eat egg)">
                            Gluten-Free<input type="checkbox" name="dietaryRequirements" value="Gluten-free"></label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <label for="giftwrap">Giftwrap?
                              yes  <input type="radio" name="giftwrap" value="yes">
                              no  <input type="radio" name="giftwrap" value="no"></label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tableRow">
            <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Place Order">
            </p>
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="col2" class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row" id="media-text">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2><b>Media</b></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 pics">
            <img src="images/cake1.jpg" id="picture1" class="img-responsive" alt="wedding cake">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 pics">
            <img src="images/cake2.jpg" id="picture2" class="img-responsive" alt="birthday cake">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 pics">
            <img src="images/cake3.jpg" id="picture3" class="img-responsive" alt="cupcakes">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Links" class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="row" id="links-text">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2><b>Links</b></h2>
            <a href="link removed">
              <h3>Facebook</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="link removed">
              <h3>5 star hygiene rating</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <h3>Reviews!</h3>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to be using bootstrap@3.3.7, instead of the latest version? (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I would start from scratch, using a recent version of bootstrap. Start simple, and try to keep your structure as clean as possible in order to avoid conflicting styles. The reason it is not stacking is because of the `display: table;` on the `.row`, the display: `table-cell;` + `float: none;` on the `[class*="col-"]`. You want the columns to fill the available screen space. This answer will help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/6009707

Comment: You have some brutally heavy-handed custom CSS in there. You're basically hacking up the very fundamental aspects of Bootstrap's grid by overriding core properties on `.row`, for example. This is just bad practice, and few will be interested in helping with that strategy.